# Why is my function not working when logic seems to be correct?

Tags: laravel

I have a function which returns if a user A is following user B, user B will be able to post on user A's profile.

The function in the model is as follows:

```
public function following()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Following::class);
}
public function isAFollower($user)
{
    return $this->following()->where(['user_id' => $user, 'following_id' => auth()->id()])->exists();
}
```

In my blade, I have the following code:

```
$profileUser->isAFollower(auth()->user()->id) == TRUE
```

Which for some reason evaluates to false. In the code, it is for sure that the user_id is following the auth()->id(), but it will not evaluate to true.

Can someone please help me understand what is going on? Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't `$profileUser->isAFollower(auth()->user()->id) == TRUE` be `$profileUser->isAFollower(auth()->user()) == TRUE` as `isAFollower()` expects a `$user` object and not an id?

Comment: you are using `auth()->id` for both `user_id` and `following_id` (unless someone can follow themselves) ?  and do you want to know if the `$profileUser` is following the authenticated user or if the authenticated user is following `$profileUser`?

Comment: @Aidan Yes but I do specify the id so that when it gets passed in it looks for the id

Comment: @lagbox I want to know if the profileUser is following the authenticated user. I have to sit and think about your response. Thanks.

Comment: in the `isAFollower()` function run `dd($user . " " . auth()->id() )` then check if the record does exist in your database with the matching conditions.

Comment: Can you please debug with us step by step? first try `dd($profileUser->following)` and tell us if it's returning something or null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know if the `$profileUser` is following some user I would adjust the method like so:

```
public function isFollowing($user)
{
    return $this->following()->where('following_id', $user)->exists();
}

if ($profileUser->isFollowing(auth()->id)) {
    ...
}
```

You want the relationship to handle the `user_id` column which would represent `$profileUser` in the case of the code example and you just want to add the condition for the `following_id`, which is who `$profileUser` is to be following.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated, Mr. lagbox. I had a function     public function isFollowing($profileUser)
    {
        return $this->following()->where(['user_id' => auth()->id(), 'following_id' => $profileUser])->exists();
    } which returned FALSE when I needed it to but I couldn't replicate for these needs.

Comment: So it seems like what you did was just get what was absolutely necessary, the user who is being followed is passed in and .... i guess my logic was wrong, I was trying to say, the user_id is the profileUser, and the person being followed is the authenticated user, but it looks like once it's nailed down to THE USER THAT IS BEING FOLLOWED, the logic works